# Invalid object name 'umbracoDomains'

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I uploaded all the files of Umbraco CMS to the my http://blog.domain.com and also modified the web.config file. When I point to blog.domain.com, it is giving an error written in the subject. The hosting type for the subdomain is physical hosting not subdomain on subfolder

So, I have a second web.config file in this subdomain. The first one is in the main domain. I hoep this doesnt make a differnce.
Here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxSqq.jpg

I checked the database user with which I am trying to login in to the DB and it has the db_owner permissions for the database.

Also, I tried googling for the similar issues to see if someone with similar error had resolved the problem. Here are some pages but I haven't been able to find a solution.
Please help! This has been pending for long! :-(

Answer (score 8):

When the Umbraco database is created, a new schema is created and all tables are created under this schema (eg. . rather than dbo.).

As the Umbraco website / db are copied, I assume that you changed the credentials, meaning the Umbraco data access layer may be trying to find tables ..

I have found that changing the schema to dbo resolves this problem and can be achieved (as long as only the Umbraco tables for you website are contained in the database) with the following SQL script:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ?'
```

For more details, I have recently written an article on copying an Umbraco Website found at the following URL:

http://www.carbonsoft.co.uk/articles/2012/06/copying-an-umbraco-instance.aspx

Although this question was asked some time ago, I hope this helps others with similar problems,

Answer (score 3):

You also get this error if you have no database in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco's datalayer is (unfortunately) case-sensitive - which means that Umbraco can't find the table umbracoDomains. Check that the table is correctly named and/or cased - if your database is case-insensitive then make sure that all your tables are lowercased, as this should work.

Answer (score -1):

carbonrb is right, when umbraco installation creates db it uses default credentials for db user. You can change schema to dbo like carbonrb advice or **create user who has default schema the same as installed by umbraco**. User cannot be in sysadmin role because it will override default schema back to dbo.